# How this step in simplification of the fraction using a logarithm can possibly work?

Tags: limits, algorithms, logarithms, exponential-function

I'm trying to understand how this step in simplification of this fraction / solving this limit can possibly work:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n^2 + 2n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^n (\ln 2)}{2n + 2} 
$$

I have the solution but trying to understand this step so that i can solve similar problems.

Comment: There is no need of that step. It is not an algebraic manipulation but rather the use of an advanced tool called L'Hospital's Rule (and most students are simply not aware of its proof or the exact conditions under which the rule applies). It is preferable to just use the fact that $2^{n}\geq \binom{n}{3}$ (via binomial theorem) and then the limit is seen to be $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [L' Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), your problem is in  [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

$$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Notice that $$\frac{d}{dx} 2^x = 2^x \ln 2$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dx} (x^2+2x) = 2x+2$$

Comment: thanks for explaining it so clearly. i looked at H rule before asking, but couldnt figure out how it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

the searched Limit is infinity, i think you have used the rules of L'Hospital, $$(2^n)'=2^n\ln(2)$$ and $$(n^2+2n)'=2n+2$$